# Divide column from textfile and add description as many numbers as in column

Tags: python, perl, csv

I have a huge text-file (2 GB) with 3 columns (tab-separated). I want to divide the 2. column, so that every number gets a separate line.

The callange for me is to add the description from column 1 and 3.

The head of the File looks like:

```
Q6GZX4  81941549; 47060116; 49237298    GO:0006355; GO:0046782; GO:0006351
Q6GZX1  81941546; 49237301              GO:0033644; GO:0016021
Q6GZW6  49237306                        GO:0005524; GO:0003677; GO:0004386
Q6GZW5  81941542; 49237307              GO:0033644; GO:0016021
```

And the output should be:

```
Q6GZX4  81941549    GO:0006355; GO:0046782; GO:0006351
Q6GZX4  47060116    GO:0006355; GO:0046782; GO:0006351
Q6GZX4  49237298    GO:0006355; GO:0046782; GO:0006351
Q6GZX1  81941546    GO:0033644; GO:0016021
Q6GZX1  49237301    GO:0033644; GO:0016021
Q6GZW6  49237306    GO:0005524; GO:0003677; GO:0004386
Q6GZW5  81941542    GO:0033644; GO:0016021
Q6GZW5  49237307    GO:0033644; GO:0016021
```

Have everyone an idea how I solve this problem with perl or python?

Comment: The first step to solving this is to put in some effort

Answer (score 2):

This could be one solution, but you really should have tried before...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};

{
    while (<DATA>) {
        my ($column1, $group1, $group2) = $_ =~ /^(\w+)\s+([\d;\s]+)(GO.*)$/;

        $group1 =~ s/\s//g; # Strip spaces / tabs
        my @list = split /;/, $group1;

        foreach my $element (@list) {
            say "$column1\t$element\t$group2";
        }
    }

}

__DATA__
Q6GZX4  81941549; 47060116; 49237298    GO:0006355; GO:0046782; GO:0006351
Q6GZX1  81941546; 49237301              GO:0033644; GO:0016021
Q6GZW6  49237306                        GO:0005524; GO:0003677; GO:0004386
Q6GZW5  81941542; 49237307              GO:0033644; GO:0016021
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the lines first by tab and then split 2nd column and use loop.

Code

```
my $filename ="abc.txt"; # provide your text filename
open FH, $filename or die "Error\n";
while(<FH>)
{
        chomp($_);
        my @arr = split(/\t/,$_);
        my @val =split(/;\s/,$arr[1]); # check the delimiter here if you have any problem
        foreach my $id (@val)
        {
                print "$arr[0]\t$id\t$arr[2]\n";
        }

}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Written as a Unix-style filter and presented with no explanation (as you don't appear to have made any effort to solve the problem before asking for a solution here).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  my @cols = split /\t/;
  foreach my $data (split /;\s+/, $cols[1]) {
    print "$cols[0]\t$data\t$cols[2]";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see some perl code !

Here is my python3 solution, didn't tried it with such a big file but curious about issues...

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                              

def next_line_formated(entry):
    key, ids, *_, values = entry.split('\t')
    for n in ids.split('; '):
        yield "{}  {}\t{}".format(key, n, values)

with open('IN', 'rt') as input_file:
    with open('OUT', 'w') as output_file:
        for entry in input_file:
            for line in next_line_formated(entry):
                output_file.write(line)
```